# Cleanest way to shorten two similar methods

Tags: java, methods

down bellow you can see two example methods, which are structured in the same way, but have to work with completely different integers.
You can guess if the code gets longer, it is pretty anoying to have a second long method which is doing the same.
Do you have any idea, how i can combine those two methods without using "if" or "switch" statements at every spot?

Thanks for your help

```
public List<> firstTestMethod(){
    if(blabla != null){
        if(blabla.getChildren().size() > 1){
            return blabla.getChildren().subList(2, blabla.getChildren().size());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And:

```
public List<> secondTestMethod(){
    if(blabla != null){
        if(blabla.getChildren().size() > 4){
            return blabla.getChildren().subList(0, 2);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Cleanliness is subjective. Questions about cosmetic improvements to working code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You can try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Check their rules before posting.

Comment: Use method parameters

Comment: combine 'if':
     if (blabla != null && blabla.getChildren().size() > 1)

Comment: Your examples make no sense as a list with more than four elements automatically has more than one element. please provide a comprehensible example

Answer (score 0):

You can pass objects that encapsulate the desired behavior differences at various points in your method. Often you can use a predefined interface for behavior encapsulation (`Runnable`, `Callable`, `Predicate`, etc.) or you may need to define your own.

```
public List<> testMethod(Predicate<BlaBlaType> test,
                         Function<BlaBlaType, List<>> extractor)
{
    if(blabla != null){
        if(test.test(blabla)){
            return extractor.apply(blabla);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You could then call it with a couple of lambdas:

```
testMethod(
    blabla -> blabla.getChildren().size() > 1,
    blabla -> blabla.getChildren().subList(2, blabla.getChildren().size())
);

testMethod(
    blabla -> blabla.getChildren().size() > 4,
    blabla -> blabla.getChildren().subList(0, 2)
);
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work out: The second snippet OP shows uses `blabla.getChildren().size` for end. But you cant just pass that in because it's only used if `blabla` isn't null. Once you actually write the code that could replace OP's second snippet with an invocation of your parameterized method, it's longer than the original. Using lambdas here could help, but isn't exception transparent, for starters. It's not a great fit.

Comment: @rzwitserloot - Yes, the first approach is flawed; I'll work on that. I agree that the second approach (with the lambdas) isn't great for this simple code, but OP suggested in the question that the actual methods were going to be quite a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to isolate common ground from 2 or more places into its own Helper method is not a good idea if you're *just* looking at what the code does without any context.

The right approach is first to define what you're actually isolating. It's not so much about the *how* (the fact that these methods look vaguely similar suggests that the how is the same, yes), but the *why*. What do these methods attempt to accomplish?

Usually, the *why* is also mostly the same. Rarely, the *why* is completely different, and the fact that the methods look similar is a pure coincidence.

Here's a key takeaway: **If the *why* is completely different but the methods look somewhat similar, you do not want to turn them into a single method. DRY is a rule of thumb, not a commandment!**

Thus, your question isn't directly answerable, because the 2 snippets are so abstractly named (`blabla` isn't all that informative), it's not possible to determine with the little context the question provides what the *why* might be.

Thus, answer the *why* question first, and usually the strategy on making a single method that can cater to both snippets here becomes trivial.

Here is an example answer: If `list` is 'valid', return the first, or last, X elements inside it. Validity is defined as follows: The list is not null, and contains at least Z entries. Otherwise, return `null`.

That's still pretty vague, and dangerously close to a 'how', but it sounds like it might describe what you have here.

An even better answer would be: `blabla` represents a family; determine the subset of children who are eligible for inheriting the property.

The reason you want this is twofold:

- It makes it *much* easier to describe a method. A method that seems to do a few completely unrelated things and is incapable of describing the rhyme or reason of any of it cannot be understood without reading the whole thing through, which takes a long time and is error-prone. A large part of why you want methods in the first place is to let the programmer (the human) abstract ideas away. Instead of remembering what these 45 lines do, all you need to remember is 'fetch the eligible kids'.
- Code changes over time. Bugs are found and need fixing. External influences change around you (APIs change, libraries change, standards change). Feature requests are a thing. Without the *why* part it is likely that one of the callers of this method grows needs that this method cannot provide, and then the 'easiest' (but not best!) solution is to just add the functionality to this method. The method will eventually grow into a 20 page monstrosity doing completely unrelated things, and having 50 parameters. To guard against this growth, define what the purpose of this method is in a way that is unlikely to spiral into 'read this book to understand what all this method is supposed to do'.

Thus, your question is not really answerable, as the 2 snippets do not make it obvious what the common thread might be, here.

Why do these methods abuse `null`? You seem to think `null` means empty list. It does not. Empty list means empty list. Shouldn't this be returning e.g. `List.of` instead of `null`? Once you fix that up, this method appears to simply be: "Give me a sublist consisting of everything except the first two elements. If the list is smaller than that or `null`, return an empty list", which is starting to move away from the 'how' and slowly towards a 'what' and 'why'. There are only 2 parameters to this generalized concept: The list, and the # of items from the start that need to be omitted.

The second snippet, on the other hand, makes no sense. Why return the first 3 elements, but only if the list has 5 or more items in it? What's the link between 3 and 5? If the answer is: "Nothing, it's a parameter", then this conundrum has far more parameters than the first snippet, and we see that whilst the code looks perhaps similar, once you start describing the why/what instead of the how, these two jobs aren't similar at all, and trying to shoehorn these 2 unrelated jobs into a single method is just going to lead to bad code now, and worse code later on as changes occur.

Let's say instead that this last snippet is trying to return all elements except the X elements at the end, returning an empty list if there are fewer than X. This matches much better with the first snippet (which does the same thing, except replace 'at the end' with 'at the start'). Then you could write:

```
// document somewhere that `blabla.getChildren()` is guaranteed to be sorted by age.

/** Returns the {@code numEldest} children. */
public List<Child> getEldest(int numEldest) {
    if (numEldest < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return getChildren(numEldest, true);
}

/** Returns all children except the {@code numEldest} ones. */
public List<Child> getAllButEldest(int numEldest) {
    if (numEldest < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return getChildren(numEldest, false);
}

private List<Child> getChildren(int numEldest, boolean include) {
    if (blabla == null) return List.of();
    List<Child> children = blabla.getChildren();

    if (numEldest >= children.size()) return include ? children : List.of();

    int startIdx = include ? 0 : numEldest;
    int endIdx = include ? numEldest : children.size();
    return children.subList(startIdx, endIdx);
}
```

Note a few stylistic tricks here:

- boolean parameters are bad, because why would you know 'true' matches up with 'I want the eldest' and 'false' matches up with 'I want the youngest'? Names are good. This snippet has 2 methods that make very clear what they do, by using names.
- That 'when extracting common ground, define the why, not the how' is a hierarchical idea - apply it all the way down, and as you get further away from the thousand-mile view, the what and how become more and more technical. That's okay. The more down to the details you get, the more private things should be.
- By having defined what this all actually means, note that the behaviour is subtly different: If you ask for the 5 eldest children and there are only 4 children, this returns those 4 children instead of `null`. That shows off some of the power of defining the 'why': Now it's a consistent idea. Returning all 4 when you ask for 'give me the 5 eldest', is no doubt 90%+ of all those who get near this code would assume happens.
- Preconditions, such as what comprises sane inputs, should always be checked. Here, we check if the numEldest param is negative and just crash out, as that makes no sense. Checks should be as early as they can reasonably be made: That way the stack traces are more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.  Pass a named `boolean` to indicate which version you want.  This also allows the list of children to be retrieved independent of the return. For lack of more meaningful names I choose `START` and `END` to indicate which parts of the list to return.

```
static boolean START = true;
static boolean END = false;
    
public List<Children> TestMethod(boolean type) {
    if (blabla != null) {
        List<Children> list = blabla.getChildren();
        int size = list.size();
        return START ?
                (size > 1 ? list.subList(0, 2) : null) :
                (size > 4 ? list.subList(2, size) :
                        null);
    }
    
    return null;
}
```